# Thumbnail of previous image instead of cancel button while camera is open

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

i want to show the thumbnail of the previous image taken by camera instead of the cancel button while camera is running ...

Is that possible ?? Need help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.  Just capture the last image, keep it in memory (or save it to disk), then use it as one of the controls. We can do this using the `overlay` property of the `Titanium.Media.showCamera` function. Here is a quick example:

First we need an overlay view to show the image.
    var overlayView = Ti.UI.createView();
    var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        width:44,
        height:44,
        left : 5
    });

```
overlayView.add(imageView);
```

Now this is the function we use to open the camera with the overlay view. Note that we don't have controls so you need to add those (for closing etc). All we do right now is set the overlays image.

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    success:function(event) {
        // called when media returned from the camera
            imageView.image = event.media;
    },
    cancel:function() {},
    error:function(error) {},
    saveToPhotoGallery:true,
    allowEditing:true,
    mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
    overlay : overlayView,
    showControls: false // This is important!
});
```

To really make this work, you may need to save the `event.media` in a global variable, or use a similiar technique make sure `overlayView`  will not be nulled out / garbage collected.

Also this is a barebones solution, not very robust, but this is the basic method I would use!